# Rhythmbox sound cuts, cracks when other programs are running

Tags: 10.10, sound, rhythmbox, pulseaudio

I upgraded to Ubuntu 10.10. When Firefox or my photo album is open the sound in Rhythmbox cracks and cuts like someone scratching a disc with a needle. On its own or with Evolution open the sound is fluid and entirely undisturbed. How can I fix this?

Comment: ...sorry, "running."

Comment: sounds to me like you have a system that is fighting for resources (especially CPU wise). Pulseaudio can cause some problems under such circumstances. Can you post some more information in your question, like your CPU, Memory and Sound Devices?

Comment: Oh dear, thanks. How do I find that info? I only know that the CPU produces a graph but I don't think snapshots can be posted. System monitor produces graph readouts. Do I write them down and post them?

Comment: The problem only started when I upgraded to 10.10. Until then it was fine.

Comment: This is a bug.  Please file one using `ubuntu-bug pulseaudio`, then close this question.

Comment: Please tell me, where and how do I file a bug report. That part goes over my head. Thanx!!

Comment: Using Applications > Accessories > Terminal, type the command I gave you above (`ubuntu-bug pulseaudio`).

Answer (score 2):

Not running the pulseaudio equalizer are you?? (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=789578)

I found many of the presets were just too much for the soundcard, levels or the headphones I was using and crackled insistantly.

Answer (score 0):

A quick bandage (but not a fix) to try is this (From Fedora Wiki)

> If the glitch-free PulseAudio exhibits
>   glitches that cannot be fixed in time
>   for F10, we can just revert to the
>   last 'traditional' PulseAudio release.
>
> To limit the problems with Alsa
>   drivers, there is now a switch
>   "tsched=0" for the module-hal-detect
>   module which will disabled glitch-free
>   mode for all sound cards globally. To
>   use this edit /etc/pulse/default.pa
>   and append "tsched=0" to the line
>   "load-module module-hal-detect" **NOTE: The line is now "load-module module-udev-detect tsched=0"**

To edit the file mentioned, press alt+f2 and type:

> gksudo gedit /etc/pulse/default.pa

To report a bug go to here to learn more:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs